# How to Automatically Answer Yes or No in Command Line in R?

Tags: r

I'm to trying to run an r-script from the command line. The script prompts a "1"/"2" input. How can I automate the answer to be 2 via a batch file?

In particular, I have the file "run.R" with the following script within:

```
require(twitteR)
oauth <- setup_twitter_oauth(cred$consumerKey, cred$consumerSecret, cred$accessToken, cred$accessTokenSecret)
# more code...
```

When running the above script from the command line - `Rscript run.R` - the function `setup_twitter_oauth` prompts the following:

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No

Selection:
```

How can I automate the answer to be 2 when running the script from the command line or through a batch file?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is the use case you need this for?

Comment: Apologies for that. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @HassanSaif make it reproducible

Comment: This really depends on how the script was written and how it is run.  If the script is using `readline`, the interaction only works when R is run in interactive mode.  See `?readline`.   In the question you will need to simplify the script down to the essentials for this problem and show how you intend to run it.

Comment: Edited with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it can help you!

You should include options(httr_oauth_cache=F) in your run.R file.

I hope this help!
(Idea took from @NicE)

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.